# how to divide string with characters and numeric

Tags: php, string, explode

I wants to divide the string in table and my need is

output:

```
// First Output
$name ='aaaa';
$first='DUT.A1';
$second='E3.3 H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h fdfd.87';
$third ='J66.H3';

// SecondOutput
$name ='bbbb';
$first='DUT.A2';
$second='F2.2 F3.1 Y1.1';
$third ='J30.A1';
```

Input:

```
$a  = "aaaa ; DUT.A1 E3.3 H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h fdfd.87 J66.H3";
$b  = "bbbb ; DUT.A2 F2.2 F3.1 Y1.1 J30.A1";
$c  = "cccc ; DUT.A3 H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h Y1.1 J45.G2";
```

A use explode function to divide the variable like

```
$exp = explode(";",$a);
$name = $exp[0];
$x = $exp[1];
$x1 = explode(" ",$x);
$total = count($x1);
$first = $x1[1];
$loop_end = $total-2;

for($i=2;$i<=$loop_end;$i++) {
    $second .= $x1[$i]."";
}
$third = $x1[$total-1]
```

;

Using to display Above output.

if i give,

```
$var  = "haha ; J1.A1 DUT.A1  DUT.A2 C1.1 C2.1 ,
              F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 ,
              F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 ,
              F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 ";
```

I wants Before Semicolon as name, String like DUT.xx as first(no spaces included ex.`DUT.A1 DUT.A2`)
The Character starts with J and After Numeric value it stored in third(ex.`J1.A1` as third 
not J after Character).  Balance Characters stored in variable Second, like (ex.

```
$second =  'C1.1 C2.1,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1';
```

)

Comment: First, it took me 5 minutes to reformat your question. Please use the `code` button in the editor, not HTML code. Second, please rephrase the question. It's hard to understand what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the desired output?

```
$arr = array(
    "aaaa ; DUT.A1 E3.3 H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h fdfd.87 J66.H3",
    "bbbb ; DUT.A2 F2.2 F3.1 Y1.1 J30.A1",
    "cccc ; DUT.A3 H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h Y1.1 J45.G2",
    "haha ; J1.A1 J1.A2 DUT.A1  DUT.A2 C1.1 C2.1 ,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 ,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 ,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 ");


foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo "<b>item</b> = $item<hr/>";
    $parts = preg_split('/\s*;\s*/',$item);

    $name = $parts[0];
    $first = array();
    $second = array();
    $third = array();

    $split = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/',$parts[1]);

    foreach ($split as $values) {
        preg_match_all('/\b[\w\d]+\.[\d\w]+\b/',$values,$value);
        $sec = array();
        foreach ($value[0] as $item) {
            preg_match('/^DUT\./',$item,$match);
            if (!empty($match[0])) {
                $first[] = $item; continue;
            }
            preg_match('/^J\d+\./',$item,$match);
            if (!empty($match[0])) {
                $third[] = $item; continue;
            }
            $sec[] = $item;
        }
        $second[] = implode(' ', $sec);
    }

    $first = implode(' ', $first);
    $second = implode(',', $second);
    $third = implode(' ', $third);

    echo 'name = ' . $name . "\n";
    echo 'first = ' . $first . "\n";
    echo 'second = ' . $second . "\n";
    echo 'third = ' . $third . "\n\n";

}
```

> **item** = aaaa ; DUT.A1 E3.3 H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h fdfd.87 J66.H3
>
> ---
>
> name = aaaa
>  first = DUT.A1
>  second = E3.3 H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h
>   fdfd.87
>  third = J66.H3
>
> **item** = bbbb ; DUT.A2 F2.2 F3.1 Y1.1 J30.A1
>
> ---
>
> name =
>   bbbb
>  first = DUT.A2
>  second = F2.2 F3.1 Y1.1
>  third =
>   J30.A1
>
> **item** = cccc ; DUT.A3 H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h Y1.1 J45.G2
>
> ---
>
> name =
>   cccc
>  first = DUT.A3
>  second = H2.3 Y3.333 h88.h Y1.1
>   third = J45.G2
>
> **item** = haha ; J1.A1 J1.A2 DUT.A1  DUT.A2 C1.1 C2.1 ,F2.1 F4.1
>   K1.1 ,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1 ,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1
>
> ---
>
> name = haha
>  first =
>   DUT.A1 DUT.A2
>  second = C1.1 C2.1,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1,F2.1 F4.1
>   K1.1,F2.1 F4.1 K1.1
>  third = J1.A1 J1.A2